background WatchConnectivity
I am writing native iOS code in a Flutter project. WatchOS app is running in the foreground and can wake up the iOS app, but it can't trigger didReceiveMessage in the iOS app.
iOS and Watch apps in the foreground can communicate with each other without any issues. However, when my app is closed, even though it wakes up, it cannot communicate. Any ideas? Should I be using a background task ios app side?
ios
import UIKit
import Flutter
import WatchConnectivity
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
    var session: WCSession?
    
    override func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
        if(WCSession.isSupported()) {
                session = WCSession.default;
                session!.delegate = self;
                session!.activate();
        }
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)

        return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }
    
    func showLocalNotification(with message: String) {
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "New Message"
        content.body = message
        content.sound = .default
        
        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 1, repeats: false)
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { (error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Notification Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
        NSLog("Notification sent")

    }
}

extension AppDelegate: WCSessionDelegate{
    
    
    
    func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {
        
    }
    
    func sessionReachabilityDidChange(_ session: WCSession) {
        print("Watch reachability: \(session.isReachable)")
    }
    
    
    func sessionDidBecomeInactive(_ session: WCSession) {
        
    }
    
    func sessionDidDeactivate(_ session: WCSession) {
        
    }
    
    func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any], replyHandler: @escaping ([String : Any]) -> Void) {
        showLocalNotification(with: "aaaa")
        guard let receivedMessage = message["msg"] as? String else {
            NSLog("Received message but failed to parse 'msg'")
            return
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if receivedMessage == "OPEN" {
                session.sendMessage(["msg": "OPENED"], replyHandler: nil, errorHandler: nil)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any] ) {
        showLocalNotification(with: "aaaa")
        guard let receivedMessage = message["msg"] as? String else {
            NSLog("Received message but failed to parse 'msg'")
            return
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if receivedMessage == "OPEN" {
                session.sendMessage(["msg": "OPENED"], replyHandler: nil, errorHandler: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}

watch
import Foundation
import WatchConnectivity
import WatchKit

class WatchViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject, WCSessionDelegate, WKExtensionDelegate {
    var session: WCSession
    @Published var incomingMessage = ""
    
    // Initialize session
    init(session: WCSession = .default) {
        self.session = session
        super.init()
        self.session.delegate = self
        session.activate()
        
    }
    // WCSessionDelegate method: called when session activation completes
    func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {
        //
    }
    // WCSessionDelegate method: receive messages
    func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any]) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let msg = message["msg"] as? String {
                self.incomingMessage = msg
                print("Received message: \(msg)")
            }
        }
    }
    // Send message to iPhone
    func sendMessage(_ message: String) {
        if session.isReachable && session.activationState == .activated {
            session.sendMessage(["msg": message], replyHandler: nil, errorHandler: nil)
            print("Send message: \(message)")
        }
    }
    // MARK: - WKExtensionDelegate Methods
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching() {
        session = WCSession.default;
    }
    
    func applicationDidBecomeActive() {
        session = WCSession.default;
    }
    
    func applicationWillResignActive() {
        session = WCSession.default;
    }
    
    func handle(_ backgroundTasks: Set<WKRefreshBackgroundTask>) {
        // Sent when the system needs to launch the application in the background to process tasks. Tasks arrive in a set, so loop through and process each one.
        for task in backgroundTasks {
            // Use a switch statement to check the task type
            switch task {
            case let backgroundTask as WKApplicationRefreshBackgroundTask:
                // Be sure to complete the background task once you’re done.
                backgroundTask.setTaskCompletedWithSnapshot(false)
            case let snapshotTask as WKSnapshotRefreshBackgroundTask:
                // Snapshot tasks have a unique completion call, make sure to set your expiration date
                snapshotTask.setTaskCompleted(restoredDefaultState: true, estimatedSnapshotExpiration: Date.distantFuture, userInfo: nil)
            case let connectivityTask as WKWatchConnectivityRefreshBackgroundTask:
                // Be sure to complete the connectivity task once you’re done.
                connectivityTask.setTaskCompletedWithSnapshot(false)
            case let urlSessionTask as WKURLSessionRefreshBackgroundTask:
                // Be sure to complete the URL session task once you’re done.
                urlSessionTask.setTaskCompletedWithSnapshot(false)
            case let relevantShortcutTask as WKRelevantShortcutRefreshBackgroundTask:
                // Be sure to complete the relevant-shortcut task once you're done.
                relevantShortcutTask.setTaskCompletedWithSnapshot(false)
            case let intentDidRunTask as WKIntentDidRunRefreshBackgroundTask:
                // Be sure to complete the intent-did-run task once you're done.
                intentDidRunTask.setTaskCompletedWithSnapshot(false)
            default:
                // make sure to complete unhandled task types
                task.setTaskCompletedWithSnapshot(false)
            }
        }
    }
}

